# How to paginate Cloud FireStore data with ReactJs and Hooks

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

The following code, connects to a Cloud FireStore collection and saves all data in an array called **cards** using the **setCards** hook.
Next, it maps over cards array and shows all of them on a single page:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { db } from '../firebase';

const FlipCard = () => {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const data = await db
        .collection('FlashCards')
        .orderBy('customId', 'asc')
        .get();
      setCards(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='scene'>
      {cards.map((card) => (
        <div key={card.id}>
          <div>
            {card.originalText}
          </div>
          <div>
            {card.translatedText}
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default FlipCard;
```

**To add pagination to the code, I tried this:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { db } from '../firebase';

const FlipCard = () => {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const data = await db
        .collection('FlashCards')
        .orderBy('customId', 'asc')
        .limit(1)
        .get();
      setCards(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const showNext = ({ card }) => {
    const fetchNextData = async () => {
      const data = await db
        .collection('FlashCards')
        .orderBy('customId', 'asc')
        .limit(1)
        .startAfter(card.customId)
        .get();
      setCards(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
    };
    fetchNextData();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className='scene'>
        {cards.map((card) => (
          <div key={card.id}>
            <div>
              {<img src={card.imgURL} alt='' />}
              {card.originalText}
            </div>
            <div>
              {card.translatedText}
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <button onClick={showNext}>Next</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default FlipCard;
```

But React complains that:

Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'customId' of undefined

Is my approach right?
How can I fix it?

Comment: you should pass the card to `showNext` function. `<button onClick={() => showNext({card: cards[cards.length - 1]})}>Next</button>`

Comment: That sounds like an answer @kkesley :)

Comment: OMG! it works. Thank you 1000 times. What about my approach? Is there anything which I could improve? Is this the right way to connect to FireStore and showing the data? Is the pagination approach good enough? Thanks again mate.

Comment: @user1941537 this is my opinion on how you can improve (it won't be part of the answer): You can minimise the duplication of the initial fetching and your `showNext` method by creating another method that focuses to fetch the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You received this undefined error because you don't pass the card object in your onClick handler.

In fact, you are passing a [synthetic event](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) to your `showNext` function by doing this `<button onClick={showNext}>Next</button>`.

To actually pass your card object, you have to call your function like this:

```
<button onClick={() => showNext({card: cards[cards.length - 1]})}>Next</button>
```

---

As for your request to comment about your implementation details, I'd put it in the comment as this is an opinion (meaning it could be wrong in certain circumstances)